# Avoid LLVM IR Optimization on certain basic blocks

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am implementing a security related pass and therefore, I am injecting a custom basic block as part of an LLVM IR function pass.

Is there a way, to mark this basic block such that later passes do not optimize this basic block?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have a very straightforward suggestion. But here's a few things to consider.

Could you apply you basic block injection after all optimizations related with the desired/required optimization level (e.g. `opt -O3`) are applied? (I suspect not, since you're asking.)

I'm also not sure which optimizations you want to avoid (depending on what you do on your basic block). For example, do you mind the effects of `-simplifycfg`? In other words, having your injected basic block merged with predecessor/successor blocks.

If the basic block code is fairly generic, maybe you could consider keep that block outlined in a separate function and provide it with any required input as parameters and marking it with `__attribute__((noinline))` to avoid [inlining](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Having said that, you could declare all memory accesses in that basic block as `volatile`, which inhibits optimizations. Take a look at [this](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#volatile-memory-accesses).

**Edit:** There is also the `Attribute::OptimizeNone` with which you can adorn a function and have it being skipped during optimization by `opt` and related passes. You can follow (aka `grep`) that attribute in `LLVM`'s source.

If that is not enough and since I'm unaware of any general blacklist/whitelist capabilities in place, 
I can only think of an onerous alternative, but I won't dare posting it yet.

Comment: Would it be possible to move the block to a separate function, set the function to optnone, but still ensure inlining?

Comment: @Nuoji which function are you referring to as an inline candidate and which one is marked as optnone? The function that is marked as optnone won't have anything inlined to it, in case it contains calls (unless something has changed in the latest LLVM version, which I doubt). Not so sure what happens when the optnone-adorned function is considered to be inlined at its call sites. I'll have a look later, but it might be easy to test.